Was Socrates actually martyred?
Was Socrates not really martyred?
https://youtu.be/id0Kkq4VHDo?t=106

Which Alexander are you referring to?

Alexander the Great. I'm starting to think that I'm dealing with an anachronism.

they lived in different historical periods.

Please remove the question.

I removed the reference to Alexander, as that was a red herring. However, the rest of the question still stands.

@Ruminator Possibly you mix-up Sophocles with the martyrdom of his protagonist Antigone. What does the linked reference tell us about a martyrdom of Sophocles?

@JoWehler Or perhaps Socrates. I'm easily confused.

@Ruminator Socrates is a better shot, but also off the mark: Socrates was sentenced to death by court, and was killed by a drink of poison mixture. See Platon's Kriton and Apology of Socrates.

Okay, well that was whom I had in mind.

So the question was about SO(4 or 5)ES?

There is a good case for saying that Socrates was killed for his beliefs. But there are complications which somewhat undermine that view.
PLato's account of his defence at his trial - the Apology gives details.
Socrates says that his most dangerous opponents are the people who have been slandering him for many years. Aristophanes' famous comedy about him (the Clouds) is the central evidence for this - and it does indeed completely misrepresent him.
He was formally accused of asebeia - impiety or lack of proper respect for the gods - and corrupting young people - exactly what the latter meant is not really clear, but it was presumably linked to his asebeia.
His reply to these accusations are 1) that he does believe in the gods and 2) that he would be an idiot to corrupt anyone deliberately because that would make them worse people. (He says that if he did corrupt anyone, it was unintentional and so he is not guilty.)
Socrates does seem to believe in some gods or other, but most likely not, or not all, of the traditional gods that most Athenians believed in.
On the second charge, the jury might have taken the view that simply teaching them that it was a good thing to question and undermine orthodox religion was corrupting them, even if Socrates didn't think it was. They might also have cared more about the outcome of his teaching than about his intentions when teaching them.
Xenophon's version of his defence has Socrates saying that he is not unhappy to die because he fears the onset of old age, illness and death. Plato's account also has him saying that he does not fear death, but gives a more high-minded reason - that death can have no terrors for a virtuous person.
Either account will fit well with the fact that he does not defend himself properly, but openly defies the Athenians, as when he says that since he has only worked to benefit the city, he should be given dinner at government expense. Not only that, but he rejects two opportunities to go into exile and avoid the trial or the execution. So there is a case for saying that his death was as much suicide as execution.
Some people argue that the real reason for his trial and execution was political. Socrates did not support democracy during the reign of the Thirty Tyrants (405 - 404 BCE). Moreover his friends, on the whole, opposed the democrats.
So there are several reasons for Socrates' death. I leave it to you to decide, on balance, whether it counts as martyrdom.
Stanford Encyclopedia - Socrates
Wikipedia - Socrates

Excellent answer, thank you so much @Ludwig V. I came across this very useful video of Socrates' defense in modern English clarified for me the accusations and S.'s defense:
https://youtu.be/id0Kkq4VHDo


All state executions are political. 2. Almost all martyrs could avoid by denial; but that's the point of being a martyr, not to.


"All state executions are political." is a bit sweeping. What is at stake in this issue is whether the people who were prosecuted were not motivated by wanting to uphold the law, but as a move in political manoeuvring. I think Socrates diagnoses their motives pretty accurately in his speech. They objected to his philosophical practice.

@Ruminator. I'm glad you like my answer. But could you change the reference to Sophocles in your question? It's really very misleading and I didn't realize what your question was for quite some time.

Sophocles was not martyred. As of Socrates - although the world "martyred" is used inside a religious context - you could say that he was martyred, as he was killed for his beleifs; but there was a trial.

So getting to Socrates... my real question was how Socrates came to be killed for his beliefs in what I thought had a more liberal, non-didactic philosophy of, "Absorb peoples but with a Greek identity. Am I mistaken on this facet of Greek life?

@Ruminator, His ideas became so "liberal" that he threatened the core of the state. At least that's how they saw it then.

Nah, of course it's rather the state that had became so tyrannical that he had to go, not the other way round...

@Julio Di Egidio, He was judged by a court of 500 independant men; this is not an indication of a tyrannical state!

(1/2) "Socrates", Wikipedia: <<Socrates was charged in a politically tense climate. In 404 BC, the Athenians had been crushed by Spartans at the decisive naval Battle of Aegospotami, and subsequently, the Spartans laid siege to Athens. They replaced the democratic government with a new, pro-oligarchic government, named the Thirty Tyrants. [...]>>

(2/2) But my objection here is not even so much one of history (and I am not a historian anyway, not even of philosophy), but a consideration of the fact that Socrates represents the last point of conjunction with eastern "philosophies", and it is past Socrates and with the death, also symbolic, of Socrates, that properly begins the history of western philosophy and thought.  --  The direction and progression here should not be reversed.

@Julio Di Egidio, the Thirty Tyrants ruled for some months in 404 bc. Socrates was executed in 399 bc, NOT during their ruling.

@Julio Di Egidio, if you beleive that the western philosophy and thought is leberal, thing again. Socrates indeed symbolizes the turning point and the starting of western philosophy, but because of his rejection. The abolishment of the "eastern" stuff from philosophy then on, is a deterioration of thinking, not a progression.

"if you beleive that the western philosophy and thought is leberal, thing again"  You said that, not me, I said "nah" to that.  I agree with the rest (and even with that, upon a non-literal reading): I could have quoted "progress" myself, but loading that word is already a personal judgment, "progression" is neutral, just not what we do with it.  Bottom line, seems to me me we do agree, though I still think my fleshing out of things was spot on....  But, of course, "you" be the judge.  :)
